# Create new column with SQL SELECT from existing column data

Tags: mysql, sql

I am looking to create a CSV with output generated from a SQL query.

Right now it is a SELECT statement which takes data from multiple tables, however i'd like to add a column as part of my output which takes specific data from an existing column and adds it to a new column as part of the csv output for easier reading.

Is this possible?

Comment: You can absolutely use expressions in your column list to generate new columns from data in existing columns. Could you provide some more specifics about what you would like to accomplish and what you have tried already that did not work?

Comment: Hi, I have a column which has lots of JSON in it and I am looking to place into a new column all the data that falls between the values 'value:' and ',title'. Then i'd like these results output into a new column that doesn't exist so it is easier to read. I am currently looking at things like regex and sql like statements

Comment: If you have JSON, you should probably look into using the actual JSON data type and functions in the [MySQL Docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json.html).